# SteelSeries Siberia 800 not working after the latest Windows 10 update

Tags: windows-10, audio, sound-card

Last night May 17, 2018 I got a Windows 10 update.

[image]

Today the sound worked fine for me until somebody came to Discord and I found out that my mic was not transmitting. So I fiddled with the Device Manager, uninstalled and installed drivers and that got my mic on the headset to work properly.

After the mic was fixed now my sound that comes through the headset is totally broken. I hear scratching sounds or robotic (metallic sounds over the sound).

When I tried having the sound go through my speakers or through one of my monitor speakers everything works fine.

I have tried doing the same for my Playback device sound, but no luck.

[image]

I have tried both with *Disable all enhancements* on and off, no change

[image]

Finally when I went into the Speaker Configuration it only says Mono. It used to say Stereo there before the Windows Update.

[image]

Does anybody has a step-by-step fix for me? Has this happened to anybody else recently after the Windows Update?

Comment: @magicandre1981 It is literally in the question that he re-installed the drivers..

Comment: disable [core isolation](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/104025-turn-off-core-isolation-memory-integrity-windows-10-a.html) that causes video card driver issues. maybe also your issue.